# Unity ARFoundation image tracking prefab location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, image-processing, scripting

I'm trying to scan marker and put a 3D object on that marker. This is working so far, but I can't seem to find a place in scripts (arFoundation scripts), where the prefab is put when referenceImage has been found. Also useful would be getting referenceImage position, so I could instantiate object myself in that position.

Any help will be appreciated a lot

Im using:

```
ARFoundation 2.2.0 preview
ARCore 2.1.0 preview
ARKit 2.2.0 preview
Unity 2019.1.8f1



//TrackedImageInfoManager.cs SCRIPT
public void OnTrackedImagesChanged(ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    /*ARTrackedImage trackedImage = null;//SOME CODE FROM FORUMS, could this be better than below uncommented code?

    for (int i = 0; i < eventArgs.added.Count; i++)
    {
        trackedImage = eventArgs.added[i];
        // instantiate AR object, set trackedImage.transform
        // use a Dictionary, the key could be the trackedImage, or the name of the reference image -> trackedImage.referenceImage.name
        // the value of the Dictionary is the AR object you instantiate.
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < eventArgs.updated.Count; i++)
    {
        trackedImage = eventArgs.updated[i];
        if (trackedImage.trackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
        //if (trackedImage.trackingState != TrackingState.None)
        {
            // set AR object to active, use Dictionary to get AR object based on trackedImage
            // you can also include TrackingState.Limited by checking for None
        }
        else
        {
            // set active to false
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < eventArgs.removed.Count; i++)
    {
        // destroy AR object, or set active to false. Use Dictionary.
    }*/ 
    //END HERE

    //WORKING CODE STARTS HERE
    foreach ( var trackedImage in eventArgs.added)
    {
        trackedImage.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f , 0.1f , 0.1f);//when object is instaniated, this handles it scale
        //trackedImage.transform.localPosition
        UpdateInfo(trackedImage);
    }

    foreach( var trackedImage in eventArgs.updated)
    {
        UpdateInfo(trackedImage);
    }


}
```

I need to find a way mess around with the instantiated prefab or just get the location, where it will be instantiated(on the referenceImage) and instantiate it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default Prefeb is set in ARTrackedImageManager as trackedImagePrefab , 
if you want to instantiate own prefab on every new image track you can change code like this

```
void UpdateInfo(ARTrackedImage trackedImage)
{

  if (trackedImage.trackingState != TrackingState.Tracking)
    {

     if(trackedImage.referenceImage.name == "ABC"){
        Instantiate(prefab1, transform.position, transform.rotation);
      }
     else if(trackedImage.referenceImage.name == "XYZ"){
        Instantiate(prefab2, transform.position, transform.rotation);
      }

    }else{
    // Destroy object if you dont want to keep
   }
}
```

Hope this code help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (trackedImage.trackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
            {
// do something
}
```

This line of code does the trick for tracking update issues.